# How to make a contingency table for a shiny application

Tags: shiny, rstudio, contingency

How can I develop a contingency table in my r studio shiny application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to `data.frame` using `as.data.frame.matrix` and then render as any other table:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
    ui=shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
        tableOutput('foo')
    )),
    server=shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
        output$foo <- renderTable({
            as.data.frame.matrix(table(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3), c(2, 2, 3, 4, 3)))
        })
    })
)
```